# Ruby error SSL_connect

Tags: ruby, rubygems

For two days, when I try to install new gems, I've received this error on my console:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/blankslate-2.1.2.4.gem)
```

It's happened since RubyGems.org's DNS update.

I've tried `gem update --system`, but it didn't help:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

I'm Windows user running:.

- Ruby v2.1.5
- Gem v2.2.2

How can I resolve my problem?

Comment: Same behavior here, only on windows since rubygems.org update.

Comment: Same issue for me too

Answer (score 3):

A one liner fixes it for Windows in an Admin prompt (assuming you have wget in your path, which you can `apt-cyg install wget` if you have cygwin & apt-cyg)

```
wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem -O C:\cacert.pem && setx /M SSL_CERT_FILE "C:\cacert.pem"
```

Or if you're too lazy to do it the secure way, just do this:

```
gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

Comment: If you don't have apt-cyg, just download that file manually and save it to C:\

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your RVM SSL certificates are up to date:

```
 rvm osx-ssl-certs status all
```

To update you can run:

```
rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
```

Comment: Hi ! i don't use rvm, i use just sass/compass/jekyll :(

Comment: Is this occuring when you are trying to install jekyll? or any other gem? Can you update the question with entire flow please.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy you might want to export http_proxy as well and try the below to see if the settings are working

export http_proxy=...

sudo -E gem list -r

Comment: so far, rvm seems a bit counter-intuitive when working with ruby within Windows and is definitely not something a general user should need to keep tabs on...I cannot even update a simple gem at this point...don't know what's changed, but this security wall is becoming a larger hurdle than I had wanted my morning to be filled with

Comment: so after some digging with rails installer for windows I found it uses something similar, so you may want refer to try this gist. https://gist.github.com/fnichol/867550

Comment: the user mentioned that he works on Windows. there is no RVM for that platform.